# select a student with max marks from student and marks table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables student and mark. students table has stid and name where marks table has stid and marks. I want to find a student with highest marks. How to do it?

Comment: Is it one-to-one i.e. one record per student in the marks table ?

Comment: The student with highest marks is the one who doesn't ask other to his homework...

Answer (score 2):

What I got from your question, you need the student with the highest mark

Try this:

```
Select st.stid ,  st.name, m.marks
from student st
inner join mark m on st.stid = m.stid
order by m.marks desc limit 1
```

Comment: Hi Sashi , Just for information  can we write above query without inner join like using sub query ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the max of average of student marks (as you wrote "student with highest **marks**" - so I assume one student has many marks.

Here the example schema, data and query:

```
create table student (
    stid int,
    name varchar(100)
)

create table mark (
    stid int,
    mark int
);

insert into student values(1, 'a');
insert into student values(2, 'b');
insert into student values(3, 'c');

insert into mark values(1, 5);
insert into mark values(1, 4);
insert into mark values(2, 6);
insert into mark values(2, 5);
insert into mark values(3, 4);
insert into mark values(3, 4);

select s.stid, s.name, a.avg_mark
from (select stid, AVG(mark) as avg_mark from mark group by stid) as a, student s
Where a.avg_mark =
    (select Max(avg_mark) as max_mark from
        (select  stid, AVG(mark) as avg_mark from mark group by stid) as x)
and
s.stid = a.stid;
```